# using transaction in multiple database

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

## Sqltransaction

I am trying to insert in to tables in the multiple db and I want to one of them is not execute ,all stetement is rooleback.
i want use sql  transaction but i dont know how to use sql transaction and transactionscope in c#
i transaction scope

```
   try
    {
     using (tScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,TOption))
      {
        
      ConAcnt.open();
     SqlCommand Com1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT",ConAcnt);
      Com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
      
      ConBase.open();
     Com2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT",ConBase);   
      Com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
       tScope.Complete();
      }

 catch (Exception ex)
{
    tScope.Dispose();                            
                                                           
}


   }
```

i want when the com2 not execute,com1 is rooleback,but commit the transaction,com2 is execute and com1 not save in db

Comment: You need to enlist the distributed transaction coordinator

Comment: What currently happens? it looks very much like this should already work. However, you should remove `TT` from that completely: you are already handling the transaction via `TransactionScope`. So: what happens with the code in the recently edited version? Remove `TT` / `tt` completely.

Comment: when remove tt but not work codes.

Comment: when is com2 not execute,i want rooleback com1,but not work,already com1 insert into ConAcnt

Answer (score 1):

You probably need [Distributed Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254973.aspx)